# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Documents/TestNote/Documents/AddNote' is not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am having two user control on a aspx page and one of the user control has a text area for notes. and i am trying to use JSON so that when they click the addnote button it does not reload the page.

Below is my java script , but it says that it is giving this error

The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Documents/TestNote/Documents/AddNote' is not allowed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btnAddNote").click(function() {
            alert("knock knock");
            var gnote = getNotes();
            //var notes = $("#txtNote").val();
            if (gnote == null) {
                alert("Note is null");
                return;

            }

            $.post("Documents/AddNote", gnote, function(data) {
                var msg = data.Msg;
                $("#resultMsg").html(msg);
            });
        });
    });

    function getNotes() {
        alert("I am in getNotes function");
        var notes = $("#txtNote").val();
        if (notes == "")
            alert("notes is empty");
        return (notes == "") ? null : { Note: notes };
    }
</script>
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNote(AdNote note)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("Note {0} added", note.Note);
        return Json(new AdNote { Note = msg });


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right controller and action? If you remove the `HttpPostAttribute` decoration does it work properly?

Comment: I dont think it's getting in to th conrtoller , as i put a break point and it's not hitting that , but do you see any thing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

in the controller use

```
return Json(new AdNote { Note = msg },sonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors:
 -  `var msg = data.Msg;` should be `var msg = data.Note;`
 -  Use `<%=Url.Action("AddNote","Documents")%>` instead of `"Documents\AddNote"`

Comment: After i made the changes u suggested it's entering the controller but not passing my dad to the controller, when i try to do Note.note, it is says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Ok, debug what your action returns (for example using firebug) and share it.

Comment: Also debug what `data` comes to `$.post`.

Comment: I think grouping my answer and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761031/asp-net-mvc-two-user-control/2761053#2761053 you can easily achieve what you want.

Comment: using firebug i checked ,its getting those as when i hover over data it says object { Note: test more...}

Comment: so `data.Note` is defined, and I think you can replace `data.Msg` with `data.Note`